# Last day of the month in .NET

Tags: .net

Normally I use the below code, but is there a better way?

```
lastOfMonth = new DateTime(Now.Year, Now.Month, 1).AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1)
```

Comment: I think only a function provided by the API would do a better job.

Comment: Do you want a specific time?  If not you should use Today, not Now.

Comment: I find your approach fine.  The approach below could be adapted to it but at the end of the day you're trying to solve a problem with a solution that is workable.

Comment: Since this works and performance doesn't matter, better would be less code.

Comment: I can't bring myself to upvote the question... It's already got 31 votes.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

I use

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Today;
var lastDate = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, DateTime.DaysInMonth(now.Year, now.Month));
```

Answer (score 14):

I would probably use `DaysInMonth` as it makes the code a bit more readable and easier to understand (although, I really like your trick :-)). This requieres a similar ammount of typing (which is quite a lot), so I would probably define an extension method:

```
DateTime LastDayOfMonth(this DateTime) {
  var days = DateTime.DaysInMonth(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month);
  return new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, days);
}
```

Now we can use `DateTime.Now.LastDayOfMonth()` which looks a lot better :-).

Comment: Broken code.... it doesn't compile because the parameter name is missing, and if you are going to make it an extension method on DateTime, it really should be based on the value of that DateTime instead of internally using Now.

Answer (score 12):

```
DateTime(year, month, DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month)).
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar.GetDaysInMonth(Now.Year, Now.Month)

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can get the number of days in the month using [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org):

```
int days = CalendarSystem.Iso.GetDaysInMonth(year, month);
```

Pretty simple, eh?  Well that assumes you know the year and month you are asking about.  If you want it for the *current* month, and in the *system's* time zone, then you have to specify that explicitly, like this:

```
DateTimeZone tz = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb.GetSystemDefault();
LocalDate localDate = SystemClock.Instance.Now.InZone(tz).Date;
int days = localDate.Calendar.GetDaysInMonth(localDate.Year, localDate.Month);
```

Noda Time intentionally makes you think about these things, instead of just making the assumptions that `DateTime.Now` or `DateTime.Today` do.